# Computing derivatives for backpropagation across a convolution step

Tags: neural-network, cnn, backpropagation, convolutional-neural-network

This will be a long post, but I hope it'll be instructive to anyone else in my position. I'm trying to find how the derivatives of the loss function are calculated with respect to the kernels and intermediate outputs of convolution layers. Here's the simple setup I'm going with for now:

For practical purposes, I've heard we generally use cross-correlation, so my entire treatment of the problem is based around that. Let $I$ be an $m\times n$ image (or an intermediate conv layer output) on which a $p\times q$ filter $K$ is used to produce output $O$. **Starting out, I'm only considering *valid* cross-correlation performed on $I$**, which means no padding. We then have:

$$O(i,j)=(I\star K) (i,j)=\sum_{u=1}^p\sum_{v=1}^qI(i+u-1,j+v-1)K(u,v)$$

where $\star$ means cross-correlation. Let $dX$ generally denote the derivative of the loss function w.r.t. the quantity $X$. Then
$$dK(u',v') = \sum_{i=1}^{m-p+1}\sum_{j=1}^{n-q+1}dO_{ij}\frac{\partial O_{ij}}{\partial K(u',v')}
\\=\sum_{i=1}^{m-p+1}\sum_{j=1}^{n-q+1}dO(i,j)I(i+u'-1,j+v'-1)
\\=\sum_{i=1}^{m-p+1}\sum_{j=1}^{n-q+1}I(u'+i-1,v'+j-1)dO(i,j) = (I\star dO)(u',v')
\\\implies dK = I\star dO$$

To find $dI$, first I can apply a change of variables to the formula for $O(i,j)$. Let $i'=i+u-1$ and $j'=j+v-1$. Corresponding to the summation limits $u=1$ and $u=p$, we have $i'=i$ and $i'=i+p-1.$ Similarly for $v$ and $j'$. We get:

$$O(i,j)=\sum_{i'=i}^{i+p-1}\sum_{j'=j}^{j+q-1}K(i'-i+1,j'-j+1)I(i',j')$$

Then
$$dI(i'',j'')=\sum_{i=1}^{m-p+1}\sum_{j=1}^{n-q+1}dO_{ij}\frac{\partial O_{ij}}{\partial I(i'',j'')}$$

Note that there will be values of $i,j$ such that $i''< i$ and/or $j''<j$ in which case the derivative $O(i,j)$ w.r.t. $I(i'',j'')$ will be zero (since the summation indices $i',j'$ in the formula for $O(i,j)$ above will start from $i,j$ respectively and won't equal $i'',j''$).

So at this point I'm stuck. **Can anyone help me out from this point on, to derive the expression for $dI$? I worked through the specific case where $m=n=4$ and $p=q=2$. In that case, it turns out that $dI=dO*K'$, where $*$ denotes *full* cross-correlation with zero-padding and $K'$ is the transposed (flipped) version of $K$. But how do I deal with the problem of indices $i'',j''$ going out of bounds in the above equations? Is there an alternative approach?**

---

Secondly, how are the formulas for $dK$ and $dI$ generalized to the case when stride $=2$ ? Again, I worked out for the specific case $m=n=4$ and $p=q=2$ as follows:

Let the stride in the $x$ ($y$) direction be $s_x$ ($s_y$). Then

$$O(i,j)=\sum_{u,v=1}^2K(u,v)I((i-1)s_y+u,(j-1)s_x+v)$$

(You can check the above formula yourself) Then

$$dK(u',v')=\sum_{i,j=1}^2dO(i,j)I(u'+(i-1)s_y,v'+(j-1)s_x)$$

I don't see any easy way of writing this in the form of a cross-correlation formula. For example, if $s_x=s_y=2$,

$$dK(2,1)=dO(1,1)I(2,1)+dO(1,2)I(2,3)+dO(2,1)I(4,1)+dO(2,2)I(4,3)$$

[image]

How does one efficiently implement an operation like this? Not to mention I haven't even touched upon what $dI$ looks like with strides greater than $1$.